# Error trying to mock redshift in python test

Tags: python, postgresql, amazon-web-services, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to use `@mock_redshift` of [moto](https://github.com/spulec/moto) to simulate the connection with AWS Redshift, I'm using boto3 to create de test cluster but when I make a query I get the following error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) could not translate host name "recon-test.cg034hpkmmjt.us-east-1.redshift.amazonaws.com" to address: Name or service not known
```

The code is the following:

```
@mock_redshift
@mock_s3
@pytest.mark.vcr
def test_extract_stp_both_dates():
    client = boto3.client('redshift', region_name='us-east-1')
    response = client.create_cluster(
        DBName='recon',
        ClusterIdentifier='recon-test',
        ClusterType='single-node',
        NodeType='ds2.xlarge',
        MasterUsername='cuenca',
        MasterUserPassword='password',
    )

    host = response['Cluster']['Endpoint']['Address']
    port = response['Cluster']['Endpoint']['Port']

    rs_client = RedshiftClient(
        'recon',
        'cuenca',
        'password',
        host,
        port,
    )

    rs_client.s.execute("CREATE TABLE table_test (attr VARCHAR);") # The error is here

    conn = boto3.resource('s3', region_name='us-east-1')
    conn.create_bucket(Bucket=os.environ['S3_BUCKET'])
    random.seed(1)
    responses.add_passthru('https://')
    extract('01/11/2018', '30/11/2018', rs_client=rs_client)
```

This is the RedshiftClient

```
import sqlalchemy as sa
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker


class RedshiftClient:
    def __init__(
        self, database: str, user: str, password: str, host: str, port: str
    ):
        self.connection_string = (
            f'redshift+psycopg2://{user}:{password}@{host}:{port}/{database}'
        )
        self.engine = sa.create_engine(self.connection_string)
        self.sessionmaker = sessionmaker(bind=self.engine)
        self.s = self.sessionmaker()

    def exec_query(self, query: str) -> list:
        return self.s.execute(query).fetchall()
```

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at the `Cluster` implementation of `moto` [in their Github](https://github.com/spulec/moto/blob/502957f1f9560cb6dff75271e6812498f4ff7bba/moto/redshift/models.py#L65).

The `mock_redshift` functionality mocks boto3's Redshift cluster management API, but not the database itself. The connection to the URL moto provides (i.e. test.cg034hpkmmjt.us-east-1.redshift.amazonaws.com) will never work.

If you would like to test real Redshift access, I think a good idea is to test with a container running Postgres, a good Python lib that provides this functionality easily is `testcontainers` ([Github link](https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-python))

You can install to your virtual env using

```
pip install testcontainers[postgresql]
```

And modify your test to include

```
from testcontainers.postgres import PostgresContainer


def test_docker_run_postgress():
    postgres_container = PostgresContainer("postgres:9.5")
    with postgres_container as postgres:
        e = sqlalchemy.create_engine(postgres.get_connection_url())
        result = e.execute("SELECT version()")
```

I would like to remark that Postgres is not the same as Redshift, in fact there are many important differences ([like highlighted in this article](https://blog.panoply.io/redshift-vs-postgressql)). For instance, one that recently affected me was that Redshift does not accept the `DISTINCT ON (column)` syntax.

Comment: the problem ist about mocking the redshift database(not the cluster). Your testcontainers code does not mock the db. It provides solely a test db in a docker, which is not what you expect normally from mocking.

Comment: My answer is about mocking the database (which moto does not do), not the cluster (which moto does). Also, my answer provides exactly the same kind of mocking functionality that moto does (for example with their S3/Dynamodb mocks)